# How to append a table inside a td using .append() in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, append

I'm trying to append a `table` inside a `<td>` element. This code works fine for `first two rows` after that, entire design of the `datatable` gets collapsed. Give me the solution for where I went wrong. Here I have tried so far.

```
$("td.text-center", row).html('');
var str = "";
str += "  <table>";
str += "   <tr>";
str += "   <td>";
str += '  <a href="#" onclick="GetContactsDetails(' + item[i].projectIcode + ')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Contacts" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100px;">Contacts</a>';
str += "      </td>";
str += "      <td>";
str += '       <a href="#" onclick="GetPhasesDetails(' + item[i].projectIcode + ')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Phases" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100px;">Phases</a>';
str += "       </td>";
str += "       </tr>";
str += "       <tr>";
str += "       <td>";
str += '      <a href="#" onclick="GetmodulesDetails(' + item[i].projectIcode + ')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Modules" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100px;">Modules</a>';
str += "      </td>";
str += "     <td>";
str += '      <a href="#" onclick="GetTechnologyDetails(' + item[i].projectIcode + ')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technologies" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100px;">Technology</a>';
str += "      </td>";
str += "      </tr>";
str += "      </table>";
$("td.text-center", row).append(str);


$("#example-datatable").append(row);
row = $("#example-datatable tbody tr:last-child").clone(true);
```

Comment: You're using datatables?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the result from list and append it using datatables...

Comment: It's not working because datatables doesn't use nested tables as you'd normally do them manually in JavaScript. [See this](http://live.datatables.net/sawapoci/1/edit)

Comment: Then any other ways there to show the content inside the <td> as like tables?

Comment: what about child row, can you use it instead as in; https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html